# Font not reflected while converting html to word document

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, ms-word

I have website in c#ASP.NET 4.0. Here am using HTML to open xml code and dll.

For doing this am going with following steps:-

1) First am open existing word doc copy some paragraph it having font "Arial".
 2) Then am parse that html to my html to word conversion code using htmltoopen xml dll.

And my c# code is Here :-

```
protected void btnExportToWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string readText = string.Empty;
        const string filename = "C:\\Temp\\ExportToDocNew1.docx";

        try
        {               
            HTMLFile = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen,print\">";
            HTMLFile += " .divPageBreak { page-break-after: always; display: block;  clear: both;}";
            HTMLFile += " table,td{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;}";
            HTMLFile += "</style></head><body><div class=\"divPageBreak\">" + "<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Effective the date of your reporting for duties, you will be eligible for salary, allowances and other benefits as specified in the enclosed annexure. The remuneration as indicated in the annexure is comprehensive and all-inclusive and hence it shall be deemed to include all the liabilities of the Company. Your remuneration package is strictly confidential between you and the Company and should not be discussed with any one nor divulged to anyone in any manner whatsoever.

" + "";

```
            using (MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.MainDocumentPart;

                    if (mainPart == null)
                    {
                        mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
                        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                    }

                    HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(mainPart);
                    Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

                    SectionProperties sectionProps = new SectionProperties();
                    PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin() { Top = 1000, Right = (UInt32Value)1008U, Bottom = 2000, Left = (UInt32Value)1008U, Header = (UInt32Value)1600U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
                    sectionProps.Append(pageMargin);
                    body.Append(sectionProps);

                    var paragraphs = converter.Parse(HTMLFile);
                    word.Application wordApp = new word.Application();
                    for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        body.Append(paragraphs[i]);
                    }

                    converter.ExcludeLinkAnchor = false;                     

                    mainPart.Document.Save();
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes(filename, generatedDocument.ToArray());
            }
           }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly posed a question that I could see, so I'll take it that you're interested in any way to honour fonts going from html to docx in C#/.NET.

I don't know about  "htmltoopen xml dll", but as an alternative, [docx4j-ImportXHTML.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j-ImportXHTML.NET/) certainly supports fonts:

```
 /**
 * Map a font family, for example "Century Gothic" in:
 * 
 *    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 * 
 * to a w:rFonts object, for example:
 * 
 *    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial Black" w:hAnsi="Arial Black"/>
 * 
 * Assuming style font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 * the first font family for which there is a mapping is the one
 * which will be used. 
 * 
 * xhtml-renderer's CSSName defaults font-family: serif
 * 
 * It is your responsibility to ensure a suitable font is available 
 * on the target system (or embedded in the docx package).  If we 
 * (eventually) support CSS @font-face, docx4j could do that
 * for you (at least for font formats we can convert to something
 * embeddable).
 * 
 * You should set these up once, for all your subsequent 
 * imports, since some stuff is cached and currently won't get updated
 * if you add fonts later.
 * 
 * @since 3.0
 */
public static void addFontMapping(String cssFontFamily, RFonts rFonts) {
    FontHandler.addFontMapping(cssFontFamily, rFonts);
}

public static void addFontMapping(String cssFontFamily, String font) {

    FontHandler.addFontMapping(cssFontFamily, font);
}
```

You can also configure defaults:

```
# docx4j-ImportXHTML.properties

docx4j-ImportXHTML.fonts.default.serif=Times New Roman

docx4j-ImportXHTML.fonts.default.sans-serif=Arial

docx4j-ImportXHTML.fonts.default.monospace=Courier New
```